# PHP Mysql query syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

For the life of me I cannot figure out this error.

```
require_once 'mysql.php'; // connect to MYSQL
-> $query = "INSERT INTO table (name, age, email, mc, sm, fit, trax, hh, claimed, handled, status)
          VALUES ('".$name."', '".$age."', '".$email."', '".$mc."', '".$sm."', '".$fit."', '".$trax."', '".$howheard."', '".$claimed."', '".$handled."', '".$status."')"; mysql_query($query) or die ('databse couldnt be updated'); echo "<br/><br/>Database updated with the information for MCID " .$mc. "<br/><br/>";
```

error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\NAMEME.php on line 80 (Where the "->" is.)

Now, all this code was working fine, until I made a change to the mysql table I am using. I added a column named "id" and made it auto-increment. Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE whitelist (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     age INT NOT NULL,
     email TEXT NOT NULL,
     minecraft TEXT NOT NULL,
     steam TEXT NOT NULL,
     fit INT NOT NULL,
     trax TEXT NOT NULL,
     howheard TEXT NOT NULL,
     claimed INT NOT NULL,
     handled INT NOT NULL,
     status INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id) ) ENGINE=MyISAMpablocdb
```

I truly cannot figure out where there is text that it wants to be a , or ;. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Silly me, thanks to the guy who suggested I look up higher. My error was that I forgot to complete an echo function. I had:

echo "Hello

a few lines above. Silly me. Thanks for the quick responses, everyone :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I get worried when I see PHP code not using [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities. I hope you are sanitizing your variables in code that hasn't been pasted here. If not, please consider re-writing the code to use PDO Prepared Statements rather than trying to sanitize your variables.

Comment: I can't find a problem with your code. All ok.

Comment: The error may be on a line further above line `80` -- that is just where the interpreter gave up. Look a few lines higher.

Comment: My variables are indeed sanitized.

Comment: Found the problem, edited question. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, printing the query would make it obvious what the error is.

Comment: close the echo: `echo"Hello";`

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is characters '->' near $query.. just remove it :D

Comment: That was just an arrow the point that that is line 80 in the file itself :P Has been fixed though. Updated the question with what solved it.